# How to fix JSON UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' error in Python?

Tags: python, json, pycharm

When trying to read from my JSON file, named "RC_2015-01", I am receiving a decoding error. The problem occurs on line 8 of the extract, "for row in f:".

The JSON file has had no problems reported from other users so I believe it is an issue with my code.

I am using python 3.7 and pycharm as my IDE.

I have tried adding multiple encoding="example" parameters to the open function but with no success.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open('RC_{}.bz2'.format(timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
        print(f)
        for row in f:
            print(row)
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            comment_id = row['name']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
```

Comment: It will have a problem, because you don't use the `json` module to parse the whole file. You can't treat JSON as a regular file and hope a parser will work by reading through lines.

Comment: Maybe open this file and try to check the line manually?

Comment: Is this actually in [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format?

Answer (score 0):

With your help, I have found the error was by trying to read directly from a zipped file, once extracted the file was able to be read with no issues.